# How to convert this JavaScript in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
  data=>{document.querySelector(
    "#os11.html-widget.gauge svg text[font-size='10px'] tspan"
    ).innerHTML = data.text
```

I tried:

```
$("#os11.html-widget.gauge svg text[font-size='10px'] tspan").document.querySelector('innerHTML')
```

But I don't know how to adjust `.action()`

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery equivalent of assigning to `.innerHTML` is using the `.html()` method.

```
data => $("#os11.html-widget.gauge svg text[font-size='10px'] tspan").html(data.text)
```

Comment: This works for several elements. How can I select a specific element to apply the function? Does something like `nth-of-type(3)` from `CSS`?

Comment: Yes, jQuery supports all CSS selectors, and also has some extensions of its own.